# Swift: why has referenced UIView its frame size as (0.0, 0.0) inside touchesBegan()?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I am just trying to carry on a simple experiment in a silly iOS app where I want to draw axes, as reference, while a draggable `UIImageView` moves upon a `UIView`. The problem is that when I can `touchesBegan()` method, the referenced `UIView` on which to draw the axes has its frame size (0.0, 0.0) and I get this error:

`Feb 14 08:44:08  Fishmeter[30272] <Error>: CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.`

Here's my code of the draggable `UIImageView`:

```
class PinImageView: UIImageView {
  var viewForAxis:AxisView!

  ...
  init(imageIcon: UIImage?, location:CGPoint, father:UIImageView, name:String, axisView:AxisView) {
    ...
    self.viewForAxis = axisView
    print(self.viewForAxis.frame.size)
    ...
  }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch: UITouch = touches.first {
        print(self.viewForAxis.frame.size)
        self.viewForAxis.hidden = false
        self.viewForAxis.pin = self
        //self.viewForAxis.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.viewForAxis.drawAxis(CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.viewForAxis.frame.origin.y), to: (CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.viewForAxis.frame.origin.y + self.viewForAxis.frame.height)))

    }
  }
}
```

where in the first `print()` I get `(303.0, 414.0)` while inside `touchesBegan()` it becomes `(0.0, 0.0)` and then I get that error. 
While the class `AxisView` is:

```
class AxisView: UIView {

var pin:PinImageView?

func drawAxis(from:CGPoint, to:CGPoint) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    switch (self.pin!.id) {
    case "redPinA","redPinB":
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        break
    case "bluePinA, bluePinB":
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        break
    default: break
    }

    /* line width of axes */
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5)

    /* draw vertical axis inside magnifier */
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y)

    /* draw horizontal axis inside magnifier */
    //CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.zoomedPoint!.x - (self.frame.size.width / 2), self.zoomedPoint!.y)
    //CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.zoomedPoint!.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2), self.zoomedPoint!.y)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}

/*override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if (pin != nil) {
        self.drawAxis(CGPointMake((self.pin?.center.x)!, self.frame.origin.y), to: CGPointMake(self.pin!.center.x, self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height))
    }
}*/

}
```

What is the correct way to do this? As you can see from comments I also tried to put everything inside `drawRect()` method but `setNeedsDisplay()` is not called as size is (0.0, 0.0)...Thank you all.

Here's what I do in my main view controller:

```
self.view.addSubview(self.axisView)
self.axisView.hidden = true

self.redPinA = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "icons/red_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(40, 110), father: self.imageView, name: "redPinA", axisView: self.axisView)

self.redPinB = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "icons/red_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(80, 110), father: self.imageView, name: "redPinB", axisView: self.axisView)

self.bluePinA = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "icons/blue_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(200, 110), father: self.imageView, name: "bluePinA", axisView: self.axisView)

self.bluePinB = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "icons/blue_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(240, 110), father: self.imageView, name: "bluePinB", axisView: self.axisView)

self.view.addSubview(self.redPinA)
self.view.addSubview(self.redPinB)
self.view.addSubview(self.bluePinA)
self.view.addSubview(self.bluePinB)
```

Comment: Where are you creating and configuring the image view? Show that code

Comment: @Wain I don't know if I have understood well, anyway I've just added some code to my question. I added a `UIView` through the interface builder to the main scroll view and I set the constraints so that is has the same size of the scroll view...

Comment: That error is correctly pointing out that that `touchesBegan` is calling `drawAxis`, which is calling `CGContext` functions, but you're not within a valid context. You don't draw anything from `touchesBegan`. You update state variables and then call `setNeedsDisplay`, which will result in `drawRect` being called, from which you can draw your axes. Or, alternatively, use `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: @Rob yes, but as you cann see from my code I also tried not to call drawAxis() in touchesBegan() but to call only setNeedsDisplay() which does not work because drawRect() is not called as the size is (0.0, 0.0)...

Comment: Fine, so let's figure out why it's 0.0,0.0, but changing it to call `drawAxis` directly should give us the precisely the error you describe. Bypassing `setNeedsDisplay` is introducing a new problem, rather than solving the first problem.

Comment: Yeah, if I call directly drawRect() I get exactly the same error... So, what Shall I do exactly? Where shall I call CG functions? Or Try CAShapeLayer?

Comment: Don't call `drawAxis` or `drawRect` yourself. Call `setNeedsDisplay`, which will result in `drawRect` being called. And you can have `drawRect` call `drawAxis`. But don't call any of these CG functions yourself (unless you're doing something like building your own context in order to build a image, which isn't applicable here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103408/discussion-between-rob-and-lory-lory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is correctly pointing out that that `touchesBegan` is calling `drawAxis`, which is calling `CGContext` functions, but you're not within a valid context (hence, "invalid context 0x0").

You shouldn't directly call any `CGContext` functions from `touchesBegan`. You can update state variables and then call `setNeedsDisplay`, which will result in `drawRect` being called by the OS, which you can draw your axes. But don't try to draw them yourself.

But I tried the following and it worked fine:

```
class AxisView: UIView {

    var pin:PinImageView?

    func drawAxis(from:CGPoint, to:CGPoint) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        switch pin!.id {
        case "redPinA", "redPinB":
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        case "bluePinA", "bluePinB":
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        default: break
        }

        /* line width of axes */
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5)

        /* draw vertical axis inside magnifier */
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y)

        /* draw horizontal axis inside magnifier */
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if pin != nil {
            drawAxis(CGPointMake(pin!.center.x, frame.origin.y), to: CGPointMake(pin!.center.x, frame.origin.y + frame.height))
        }
    }

}


class PinImageView: UIImageView {

    var lastLocation:CGPoint!
    var id:String!
    var viewForAxis:AxisView!

    init(imageIcon: UIImage?, location:CGPoint, name:String, axisView:AxisView) {

        super.init(image: imageIcon)
        lastLocation = location
        id = name

        viewForAxis = axisView
        print(viewForAxis.frame.size)
        center = location
        frame = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 40.0, height: 60.0)

        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let _ = touches.first {
            print(viewForAxis.frame.size)
            viewForAxis.hidden = false
            viewForAxis.pin = self
            viewForAxis.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        viewForAxis.hidden = true
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch: UITouch = touches.first {
            center = touch.locationInView(superview)
            viewForAxis.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var axisView: AxisView!
    var redPinA: PinImageView!
    var redPinB: PinImageView!
    var bluePinA: PinImageView!
    var bluePinB: PinImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        axisView = AxisView()
        axisView.frame = view.bounds
        axisView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        view.addSubview(axisView)
        axisView.hidden = true

        redPinA = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "red_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(40, 110), name: "redPinA", axisView: axisView)

        redPinB = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "red_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(80, 110), name: "redPinB", axisView: axisView)

        bluePinA = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "blue_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(200, 110), name: "bluePinA", axisView: axisView)

        bluePinB = PinImageView(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "blue_pin.png"), location: CGPointMake(240, 110), name: "bluePinB", axisView: axisView)

        view.addSubview(redPinA)
        view.addSubview(redPinB)
        view.addSubview(bluePinA)
        view.addSubview(bluePinB)
    }

}
```

I'm inferring from your comments that you tried calling this code directly to get around some problem that `setNeedsDisplay` wasn't resulting in `drawRect` getting called. That sounds like a separate problem. The solution is not calling `drawRect` (or `drawAxis`) yourself, but rather find out why `setNeedsDisplay` wasn't doing the job. But the problem does not rest in the code in your question, but rather is apparently a result of some other issue.